# Dog chewed the bottom part of the door frame. How do I fix it?

Tags: door-frame

Is there any way to fix it and make it look somewhat presentable (doesn't have to be perfect)?  How do I find a matching frame? How do I match the paint?

[image: door frame to bedroom]

Comment: That's a great overview picture, thanks for including it. If you would please [edit] in a closer shot so people can see the extent of the damage, that would be even better.

Comment: @FreeMan Quite a bit of detail in the existing pic if you click on it. Almost enough to make out that the doorjamb is made of MDF (how horrible if so), but not quite certain.

Comment: This question bears a lot of resemblance to the linked duplicate, right down to exact phrasing in several cases. I suspect a chat bot.

Answer (score 1):

First, using a chisel or sharp knife, carefully peel off a short section of the paint and take it to the paint dept. of a big box store, they have scanners than can scan the section and then the computer operates the paint mixer to make an exact match. Ask for a sample can of the mix, generally about $5.00 That will be more than enough to paint it.  Next:  Get some paintable wood filler and simply fill in the damaged areas, it may take a few passes, waiting for it to dry between layers, but it should work, an expired credit card, knife or who knows what else will help smooth it out. If you really want to be a perfectionist, you may need to sand the final coat lightly before painting.